# How to create bootable CentOS7 USB drive with FakeRAID drivers?

Tags: raid, bootable-media, centos-7, fakeraid

I have a few older servers that only have one available USB port, and no CD-ROM drives. I have successfully created a bootable thumb drive using dd to copy the CentOS-7-DVD isos to thumb drives, but I have gotten stuck on needing the driver(s) for the FakeRAID Intel Integrated RAID II Controller. I only have space for three disks in the servers, and I really want to use the RAID controller to run RAID 5, rather than software-based RAID 1.

The iso image for CentOS is strange, in that it contains two partitions...the iso and an anaconda partition. Although I have plenty of space left on my 8 GB flash drive, I have not been able to figure out how to add the driver file(s) to my USB drive and still have it boot successfully to the installer. I have tried adding the files to the drive after dd'ing the image, and it says there is not enough space for the driver file. I have tried resizing the partitions on a working USB drive, but I get a lot of GPT signature/msdos errors. And, I have tried partitioning the drive first and making the first partition with the CentOS iso bootable, but then I can't boot from it. I must be missing something.

How do I make a bootable CentOS7 USB thumb drive that also contains FakeRAID drivers?

EDIT: I cleared up a second USB port on the back of the servers, and put the driver disk image on a second USB...so, maybe this is the best option I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared up a second USB port on the back of the servers, and put the driver disk image on a second USB. Probably this is the best option I have.